# Django startup error on IIS

Tags: python, django, iis

When I try to start my Django app on IIS I have the error such below:

> Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ddr\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ddr\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER")) File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ddr\wfastcgi.py", line 605, in get_wsgi_handler handler = handler() File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application django.setup() File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 17, in setup configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 48, in *getattr* self._setup(name) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 44, in setup self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 92, in init mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module import__(name) File ".\config\settings\production.py", line 21, in  SECRET_KEY = env("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY") File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 117, in call_ return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 250, in get_value raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DJANGO_SECRET_KEY environment variable StdOut: StdErr:

Django secret key is written in handler mappings.

Maybe someone had the such error and know what I should do? Thank you all.

Comment: Looks like it expects to find a `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` environment variable.  Set it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have followed, and then checked, and then followed, and if things still go awry, go over the directions provided by Matt Woodward on his extremely comprehensive blog post: 
http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html

I have followed this intimately and have my django app working fine. However, I am using Python 3.6.3, Matt uses 3.5.2 and I see you are back on 2.7, so there the problem may lie.

Comment: Thank you! I try to do this.